# Terminal "xed" command missing after new Xcode install

Tags: xcode

I rely on the "xed" command from the terminal to open code files when working with Xcode. On a new Mac, I've tried installing Xcode 4.1 and 4.2 beta yet the "xed" command isn't being found in terminal after either installation. Sadly I'm not finding a terribly bountiful amount of information on multiple search engines that I've tried. Has anyone else had this issue, and how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out the answer for this, so putting it here for others.

When installing Xcode 4.2, it doesn't add its bin to the path, therefore making xed unavailable.

To do so, edit your .bash_profile (or equivalent) and add:

```
export PATH="/Developer/usr/bin:${PATH}"
```